# Number of possiblities - N choose K?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I have $N$ particles, with $m$ particles in state 1 and $N-m$ particles in state 2. These $N$ particles are placed in $N_s$ sites, where $N_s > N$. What are the total number of states or ways this can be done in the system?

I think it would be:

$$ \frac{N_s!}{N! (N_s - N)!} \frac{N!}{m!(N-m)!} = \frac{N_s!}{m! (N-m)!(N_s-N)!}$$

Is this correct? I'm having a hard time convincing myself that this is right.

Answer (score 0):

Your left side says you choose the $N$ sites out of $N_g$ first, then choose which of those $N$ have particles in state $1$.  That is a fine approach.  Alternately, you could choose the $m$ sites for the state $1$ particles, then the $N-m$ ones for state $2$ particles, getting $$\frac{N_g!}{m!(N_g-m)!}\frac {(N_g-m)!}{(N-m)!(N_g-N)!}$$ which (surprise!) looks the same.

Answer (score 0):

First choose m out of Ng spaces. Then choose (N-m) out of the remaining (Ng-m) spaces.

This can be done in C(m,Ng).C(N-m,Ng-m) ways.

This is in fact Ng!(Ng-m)!/(Ng-m)!(Ng-N)!m!(N-m)! = Ng!/(Ng-N)!m!(N-m)!